# Connecting to SQL Server from Rstudio

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

I want to connect to SQL Server from Rstudio and have tried this:

```
conection <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver="ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server", server="10.5.119.60:1433",database="my_database",uid="my_username", pwd="my_password")
```

Note: server IP is randomized for the purpose of the public post.

However, I get an error from running this code:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 08001: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for
> SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87].
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]A network-related or
> instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
> to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
> instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
> remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)

Comment: There's a seperate keyword for port specification, i.e.: `server="nomnom.org", port=2345`. Does your connection work if you remove the `:1433` and use `server="10.5.119.60"`?